# Magento Community Fatal Error Code call to a member function getAttributeid() on boolean on...Line 108

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to add a configurable product on Magento CE 1.9 and i'm experiencing a Fatal Error: call to a member function getAttributeid() on boolean on...Line 108

This is Line 108:

```
if ($attribute->getAttributeId() == $listSwatchAttr->getAttributeId()

        }

        /* @var $parentProduct Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        foreach($parentProducts as $parentProduct) {
            $mapping = array();
            $listSwatchValues = array();

            /* @var $attribute Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute */
            foreach($attributeCollection as $attribute) {
                /* @var $childProduct Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
                if(!is_array($parentProduct->getChildrenProducts())) {
                    continue;
                }

                foreach($parentProduct->getChildrenProducts() as $childProduct) {
                    $attributeValue = $childProduct->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode());

                    if(empty($attributeValue)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $attributeLabel = null;
                    if(!isset($attributeLabels[$attributeValue])) { //no label at all
                        continue; //skip
                    }
                    if(isset($attributeLabels[$attributeValue][$storeId])) { //prefer store-specific value
                        $attributeLabel = $attributeLabels[$attributeValue][$storeId];
                    } else if(isset($attributeLabels[$attributeValue][0])) { //fall back to default value
                        $attributeLabel = $attributeLabels[$attributeValue][0];
                    }

                    if(!isset($mapping[$attributeLabel])) {
                        $mapping[$attributeLabel] = array();
                    }
                    $mapping[$attributeLabel][] = $childProduct->getId();
                    $mapping[$attributeLabel] = array_unique($mapping[$attributeLabel]);

                    if ($attribute->getAttributeId() == $listSwatchAttr->getAttributeId()
                        && !in_array($attributeLabel, $listSwatchValues)) {
                        $listSwatchValues[$attributeValue] = $attributeLabel;
                    }
                } //end looping child products
            } //end looping attributes

            $parentProduct->setChildAttributeLabelMapping($mapping)
                ->setListSwatchAttrValues($listSwatchValues);
        } //end looping parent products
    }
```

Any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace to give some context

Comment: Have you modify core files?

Comment: No I haven't modified any core files.